# error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive] in the given set of commands

Tags: c++, c

I have c++ file like below one,

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

extern "C" {
    #include "sample_publish.c"
}


int main() 
{ 

    int antenna_id = 123; 
    send_message_to_mqtt(&antenna_id);

}
```

I have included a c file in c++ file and I need to pass the variable antenna_id to the function send_message_to_mqtt and the same is in c file like below one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"

void send_message_to_mqtt(int *antenna_id) {
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;

    MQTTClient_create(&client, "tcp://mqtt1.mindlogic.com:1883", "ExampleClientPub",
    MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    printf("DATA FROM C++:::%d\n", *antenna_id);

    char payload_data[] = "hi";

    //pubmsg.payload = payload_data;
    pubmsg.payload = *antenna_id
    pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(*antenna_id);
    pubmsg.qos = 1;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, "MQTT-Examples", &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n""on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",(int)(10000L/1000), "Hello World!", "MQTT-Examples", "ExampleClientPub");
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, 10000L);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    // return rc;
}
```

When I execute a c++ file, the antenna_id variable is doesnt accessible in c file which in turn not allowing me to map against pubmsg.payload and this is due to the below error,

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-5379:~/workspace_folder$ g++ sample.cpp -o sample -lpaho-mqtt3c
In file included from sample.cpp:5:0:
sample_publish.c: In function ‘void send_message_to_mqtt(int*)’:
sample_publish.c:30:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
     pubmsg.payload = *antenna_id
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
sample_publish.c:31:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘pubmsg’
     pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(*antenna_id);
     ^~~~~~
```

How to overcome this one?

Comment: First of all, never `#include` source files! Use proper project management and build separate object files that are then linked together to create the executable program.

Comment: Secondly, *where* do you get this error? Please [edit] your question to add a comment on that line. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output (as text!) into the question body. And please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Anudeep Karunakaran,  Explain what you want this code to do: `pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(*antenna_id);`.  Do you want `pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)sizeof(*antenna_id);`? or trying to convert an `int` to a _string_?

Comment: `extern "C"` does NOT mean "this code is in the C language". Everything inside it is still C++ code. It just means "these declarations can be defined or used in C source".

Comment: You *cannot* mix C and C++ with the same compiler. use a C++ frontend (eg. g++) for C++, and a C frontend (gcc) for C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess on the problem, it's most likely this line:

```
pubmsg.payload = *antenna_id
```

Besides missing the semicolon, the payload is a *pointer* to the first byte of the data to be sent. That is, you should not dereference the pointer:

```
pubmsg.payload = antenna_id;
```

---

On a related note, this line is also *very* wrong:

```
pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(*antenna_id);
```

The `strlen` function is to get the length if a *null-terminate byte **string***.

The length of an `int` can be gotten with the `sizeof` operator:

```
pubmsg.payloadlen = sizeof *antenna_id;
```

Note that here you *must* use the dereference operator, otherwise you get the size of the pointer itself.